# Locally conserved current from covariantly conserved current

Tags: conservation-laws, gauge-theory, noethers-theorem, yang-mills

In a non-abelian Yang-Mills theory, with structure group $G$, where the gauge field interacts with some matter field, the Yang-Mills equations read ${{\nabla }_{\mu }}{{F}^{\mu \nu }}={{J}^{\nu }}$, where ${{J}^{\nu }}$ is the matter current (no matter how it is defined) with values in $\mathfrak{g}$. By the antisymmetry$^*$ of ${{F}^{\mu \nu }}$ we get the covariant conservation of ${{J}^{\mu }}$:
$${{\nabla }_{\mu }}{{J}^{\mu }}=0$$
By this equation we cannot directly define a globally conserved charge, since we need a local conservation law to do this.

I thought of two different (?) methods to define a locally conserved current:

1. define a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued field $\zeta_X$ that is covariantly constant (i.e. ${\nabla }_{\mu}\zeta_X=0$) and, thus, can be constructed by parallel-transporting an initial vector $X\in\mathfrak{g}$. Then the currents $j_X^\mu:=\left<{J^\mu,\zeta_X}\right>$ will be locally conserved:
   $${\partial_\mu}{j_X^\mu}=\left<{\nabla }_{\mu}{J^\mu},\zeta_X\right>+\left<J^\mu,{\nabla }_{\mu}{\zeta_X}\right>=0$$
   for any $X\in\mathfrak{g}$.
2. re-writting the Yang-Mills equation as $\partial_\mu{F}^{\mu\nu}=J^\nu-\left[A_\mu,F^{\mu\nu}\right]$ and taking into account the antisymmetry of $F^{\mu\nu}$ we deduce that the current $j^\mu:=J^\mu-\left[A_\mu,F^{\mu\nu}\right]$ is also locally conserved. Then, we can define the projections $\tilde{j}_X^\mu:=\left<j^\mu,X\right>$, which are all locally conserved currents, for any $X\in\mathfrak{g}$.

**My questions are:**

1. are these two currents somehow related to each other or are they completely independent? If yes, how?
2. in the case where they are not related, what would be the physical meaning of the globally-conserved charges related to each one of the currents?
3. which method, if any, is used in gauge theory so as to define globally conserved charges by a covariant conservation law?

---

(*) $0=\left[F_{\mu\nu},F^{\mu\nu}\right]=\operatorname{ad}\left(F_{\mu\nu}\right)F^{\mu\nu}=\left[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu\right]F^{\mu\nu}=-2\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu{F}^{\mu\nu}=-2\nabla_\nu{J}^\nu$